# How to test one function that calls another function inside of it

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I'm using module pytest to do testing

Problem: When i run the pytest, it works fine, but how do i stop it from calling a function within the function i'm testing

e.g.

```py
def download_csv(self):
    # code here will download csv

    # I want to test code up until here and dont run the decompress_csv() function
    self.decompress_csv()


# assume this function is in a separate test file
def test_download_csv():
    assert download_csv() == # i will check if it downloaded
```

Comment: You should mock the function, which really is a method, isn't it? It's important since mocking a method is done a bit differently. Show us enough code to have a working example.

Comment: @KlausD. i have heard of mock, but have never used nor don't know how to implement it, can you give an example of how to implement a basic mock

Answer (score 4):

You would "mock" that function to return a value that allows testing of the rest of the logic in the system under test (in this case, the `download_csv` method).

Assuming we have a requirements.txt like this,

```
pytest
mock
```

with a file `test.py` like this, we can mock the `decompress_csv` function.

```
import mock


def decompress_csv():
    raise Exception("This will never be called by the test below")


def download_csv():
    decompressed = decompress_csv()
    return f"{decompressed} downloaded and processed"


def test_download_csv():
    # These additional variables are just to underscore what's going on:
    module_that_contains_function_to_be_mocked = 'test'
    mock_target = f"{module_that_contains_function_to_be_mocked}.decompress_csv"

    with mock.patch(mock_target, return_value='fake decompressed output'):
        assert download_csv() == "fake decompressed output downloaded and processed"
```

Note that in a normal situation your test code will likely be in a file different from the code it's testing; that's why I pointed out that the `module_that_contains_function_to_be_mocked` is critical.